# Why do my lawyers want to keep copies of our green cards?

Tags: united-states

My company hired a law company to apply green card for me and my family. They did a good job, we all have green cards now.

However, they asked for copies of all our green cards, and I don't feel comfortable at all, given the fact that they already have all of our informations, e.g. passports, SSNs, etc etc

I plan to reject this request. However, I wonder if there is any valid/legal reason that they want to keep a copy of our green cards.

Comment: If they have all of your other information, you don't gain any privacy benefits from withholding this information. They probably want copies (1) to be able to prove that their representation was successful if this is ever questioned, and (2) to be able to have accurate facts with which to represent you if you lose your green cards or if an issue comes up in the future.

Comment: What harm can be done with a copy of your green card (that cannot be done with copies of your passports, SSN/TINs, etc. that they already possess)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't be so quick to refuse; they are representing you, and working for your company. Ask the law firm and your work supervisor why the firm wants copies.

Realize that the law firm and the lawyers are legally bound to work in your best interest in terms of immigration, your green cards and the security of your personal information. See [California Bar - Rules of Professional Conduct](http://www.calbar.ca.gov/Attorneys/Conduct-Discipline/Rules/Rules-of-Professional-Conduct).

Such personal information is very likely to be secure with them, as it is punishable by law if sensitive information like SSNs is stolen or leaked, and could be a breach of rules of the California Bar, too.